# Where is my disk space going?

Tags: windows-7, storage, ntfs

I have a 1TB partition mounted with all my local non-program data in it, and it was showing as only having <250 GB of space left.

[image: Media drive info]

So I went to do what I usually do, move the worst of it onto my NAS as an archive, delete anything that I don't want any more, so with thi in mind I fired up windirstat - this however only showed me as having >300GB in use. This doesn't seem right - I thought maybe windirstat wasn't looking in some folders, so I selected everything in the root of the drive and hit properties:

[image]

What is going on here? How do I reclaim this space? I need to reclaim some of this space soon as I'm about to junk an old 750GB usb drive which is looking a bit suspicious and want to dump most of its contents on my pc while I look for its replacement...

Comment: Are volume shadow copies enabled? They can claim a lot of storage space and don't show up in the directory stats.

Comment: just scanned your question. try treesize by jam to view how space is used

Comment: @DavidFoerster Not quite sure how to confirm, but the best I could do was check system/system protection, which shows as off (I use norton to back up to my NAS)

Comment: @barlop I already use windirstat to do the same, as mentioned in the question. The problem is that only half of the used disk space is showing up

Comment: @DavidFoerster ok so as a belt-and-braces exercise I followed the instructions on [sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/166102-shadow-copies-delete.html) and made sure any shadow copies for M: were deleted - still no more space...

Comment: It may take a while until the blocks recently used by VSC are marked free. (I don't know if Windows does this immediately or at a later time. Competing file systems like Btrfs need a background service to run periodically to do that job.) I'm not an authority on the topic though because my knowledge of NTFS is mostly academic now.

Comment: Did you already tried to `chkdsk` this disk? You also might find [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/07/03/ntfs-misreports-free-space.aspx) interesting.

Comment: have you considered copying the data off the drive, delete the partition, and copy it back on(and consider the drive as possibly having an issue, so keeping an eye on it / labelling it)?

Comment: @barlop I'm rather hoping it's not the drive, seeing as it is a 2TB drive with 3 other partitions on it, however none of the other partitions show this problem - I've scheduled a chkdsk

Comment: I also see you're having the compress-tag on with this volume. Do you really need it? I always found compressing a volume gives more trouble (like speed and memory issues) than it's worth. I always shiver when i see blue files in explorer on old winxp systems with performence trouble. (Then somebody did a disk clean up and didn't pay attention to the options;()

Comment: You might want to decompress first. That may be your problem. With lots of small files compression might even take in more space. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/605398/why-does-ntfs-compression-take-up-a-lot-of-space).

Comment: run TreeSizeFree (as admin), this is the best tool to see where the data are stored

Comment: @magicandre1981 please explain the benefit over windirstat which I have already used

Comment: with it you can see easier which folders take most space.

Comment: The problem is that it's not the folders that take the space. Did you do a `chkdsk` without fix and wrote the numbers down? What space did the system take? It's a seperate entry from the user files. And do the numbers add up? Maybe paste it in the question. And did you remove the compression?