# Losing storage space on Windows 8.1 by compressing and decompressing the disk

Tags: windows-8.1, compression, acer-aspire

At first I thought if I compress the disk, then I would get extra space. However, after doing the compression I lost 2.5GB. Then, I decompress the whole disk to regain the lost 2.5GB but I lost 1GB more!

I ran disk cleanup and ccleaner but it did not help. I also restart the Tablet PC but it didn't help neither. I have Acer switch 10.

Comment: These actions are not the reason you are losing disk space.  Use a utility to view how your disk usage is being used.  It will give you an idea of what is actually happening.

Comment: Is Do you have any specific utility in mind?

Comment: Use the tool of your choice.

Comment: Try http://madebyevan.com/diskitude/ to know what consumes space. Also I would check unnecessary system restore points, hiberfile.sys (temporary disabling hibernation could help), and swapfile size.

Comment: @Ramhound I used a utility. There is almost no video/picture or document. The majority of the used space in the other files category which themselves are located in Windows folder and Program Files folder.
For example the system32 folder on the decompressed disk has a size of 2.5GB and a size on disk of 1.4 GB.

Comment: @yashar - You do understand that unless you are running the program with Administrator permissions it can only access files that you can access.  This means it cannot profile the disk usage for files you normally could not access.

Comment: @Ramhound I gave it administrative permissions but nothing changed. I guess it's better to reset it to factory settings.

Comment: @yashar - The reason I don't recomend software is because the software  like might not be software you like.  I personally wouldn't have even tried diskitude, it does not look like it does what you wanted, there are existing questions that suggest quality alternatives.  You can do a restoration to factory setting but this issue will just happen again, and its not an actual issue, but do what you think is best.

Answer (score 1):

A file that has already been compressed by a reasonably good compression algorithm will typically not compress well if you try to compress it again with another. In fact, in the worst case, “compressing” a compressed file can sometimes even make it bigger. Many files that you use every day are already compressed. Typically audio, video, and image formats are already using compression algorithms as part of the file format. MP3, JPEG, MPG, and similar file types are all already compressed and typically do not benefit much, if at all, from attempts to compress them further.

Another less likely culprit could be
that yourcomputer could be making a system restore point after compressing / decompressing all those files check your restore points to see if they correlate to the changes

Also your drive could have become severely fragmented check your drives fragmentation.

Use caution if you are using a SSD as lots of file operations can shorten the life of the drive.

Comment: There is no system restore point in my laptop.

Comment: You may be trying to compress files that were already compressed and therefore accidentally made them larger and then even larger when uncompressed.

Comment: Take a look at this it might explain better what's happening with your situation http://superuser.com/questions/605398/why-does-ntfs-compression-take-up-a-lot-of-space